# The effect of Measurement error on a Beta Coefficient

Tags: regression-coefficients, bias, measurement-error

I am trying to show the bias of the slope coefficient that occurs when there is measurement error in the regressor.

$$ Y = a + B* x_{i} + e_{i} $$

To find the beta coefficient, we can use the formula below:

$$ Beta_{hat} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n     \frac{ (x_{i}* -  x_{hat}*) * (y_{i} - y_{hat}) }{ (x_{i} - x_{hat}^2 ) } $$

If:

$$ x_{i}* = x_{i} + v_{i} $$

$$ vi = N( u_{v}, \sigma_{v}^2) $$

Then:

$$ x_{hat}* = x_{hat} + U_{v} $$

$$ Y = a + B(x_{i} + v_{i}) + e_{i} $$

$$ Y_{hat} = a + B*x_{hat} + B*(U_{v}) $$

Plugging in the above information we get:

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{ ( a + B(x_{i} + v_{i}) + e_{i}  - a - B*x_{hat} - B*(U_{v} ) ) * (x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat} - U_{v} )} { (x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat} - U_{v})^2 } $$

Which simplifies to:

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{ B*(x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat} - U_{v})^2 + ei*( x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat}  - U_{v} ) }{  (x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat} - U_{v} )^2 } $$

Which again simplifies to:

$$ B_{hat} = B +    \sum\limits_{i=1}^n   \frac{ ei*( x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat}  - U_{v} ) }{  (x_{i} + v_{i} - x_{hat} - U_{v})^2  } $$

How should I interpret that last term? I know that Beta should be biased, and that its bias should be dictated by the variance of ME but I am not sure how to see that through this term?

Thanks